# Translation invariant set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Trying to prove that two things here....where we define $A+x=\{a+x:a\in A\}$

$\tag{1}(A+x)^c=A^c+x$ for any $A\subseteq \Bbb R^m$ and for every $x\in \Bbb R^m$
and

$\tag{2}\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(A_{n}+x)=(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n})+x$  for every $x\in \Bbb R^m$

I feel like we should be able to show both of this without needing the definition that $A=(a_{1},b_{1}]\times...\times(a_{m},b_{m}]$ where $A$ is in the m-th order Borel Set, hence a sigma-algebra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might be misinterpreting the question here, so correct me if I fumbled this terribly:

Both (1) and (2) are true for any $A\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}^m$, and the proofs don't rely on measure theory or the structure of $A$ at all. It's just a simple set-theoretic argument:

Let $y\in (A+x)^c$. Then $y\notin A+x$, so $y-x\notin A$. Thus $y-x\in A^c$, so $y\in A^c+x$. The reverse inclusion is proven by following this argument backwards.

Similarly, if $y\in \bigcup (A_n+x)$, then $y\in A_n+x$ for some $n$. Thus $y-x\in A_n$, meaning $y-x\in \bigcup A_n$. Therefore $y\in \bigcup A_n+x$, and we can again follow this argument backwards for the reverse.

This shows that (1) and (2) hold in any set $X$ with the structure of an additive group.

Comment: You're confused because the solution is so simple haha....thanks a lot! Makes perfect sense.